# How do I add captions to a picture in windows live writer?

Tags: windows-7, blogging, windows-live-writer

I just started to use Windows Live Writer and love the interface especially with the drag and drop pictures.  However I cannot seem to be able to add captions below the images... How do I do this?  Is there a plugin for that or am I just missing the procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two methods for doing this.

1. You can use the watermark text option in the advanced area of the image insert option.

2 you can download the Polaroid Picture Plugin and use the space it creates below the picture to create the caption.

These two methods are written up here in more detail: http://windowslive.com/Connect/Post/3ce38b21-ee9e-40b8-bf28-bb81671158db

3. You can set the image in a table 2 rows tall and 1 column wide and place the caption below the image and hide the borders of the table by setting them to zero.

Comment: This is what I ended up using